# Stop word wrapping in VS2008 (vb)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, search, word-wrap

Unfortunately VS2008 has wrapped some of my code automatically, this isnt helpful for searching as it has wrapped at points that has resulted in split names of variables in my designer project.
e.g.  Variable named MyVariable would appear as below:

```
    "MyVar", & _
    "iable"
```

This means i cant search for these variables. Is there any way that i can prevent VS from wrapping like this? Alternatively is there any way that i could search for a variable like this even if it is wrapped?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not a variable, it's a string constant. Or two, rather. Did VS really split your string constant in two?

Comment: I've never seen it wrap like that.  Its just a visualization thing - there's still only 1 line.

Comment: This is what word wrap does: http://bit.ly/UWxhk

you're describing something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off word wrapping in VB code by going to `Tools/Options` menu, under `Text Editors/VB.NET`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your secondary question:

Find (CTRL+F),
select "Search hidden text" and "Use: Regular expressions"

searching for

```
"Class.*\n.*Inherits"
```

Will find

```
Public (HERE)Class Form1
   Inherits(TO HERE) System.Windows.Forms.Form
```